# Avoid Redundant Parameters for Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm creating a helper class for my JavaFX application as follows:

```
public class ViewHelper<T extends Parent, U extends Controller> {
    private static final String FXML_EXTENSION = ".fxml";
    private final Class<? extends Controller> clazz;
    private FXMLLoader loader;
    private T t;

    public ViewHelper(Class<? extends Controller> clazz) throws IOException {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.load();
    }

    private void load() throws IOException {
        this.loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl());
        this.t = this.loader.load();
    }

    private URL fxmlUrl() {
        return clazz.getResource(clazz.getSimpleName() + FXML_EXTENSION);
    }

    public T component() {
        return t;
    }

    public U controller() {
        return loader.getController();
    }
}
```

The usage is:

```
var viewHelper = new ViewHelper<BorderPane, MainController>(MainController.class);
BorderPane borderPane = viewHelper.component();
MainController mainController = viewHelper.controller();
```

It actually works and achieves what I want. However, it irritates me to see I have to pass `MainController` twice when at all times they are the same. No instance that they are not the same. How can I avoid one of them during instance creation of `ViewHelper`?

Instead of:

```
var viewHelper = new ViewHelper<BorderPane, MainController>(MainController.class);
```

I would prefer something like:

```
var viewHelper = new ViewHelper<BorderPane>(MainController.class);
```

or:

```
var viewHelper = new ViewHelper<BorderPane, MainController>();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"when at all times they are the same"* They don't have to be the same, e.g. `new ViewHelper<BorderPane, Controller1>(Controller2.class)` is valid too. If the parameter has to be the same as the generic type, then the parameter type would be `Class<U>`, not the `Class<? extends Controller>` that it is. There is no required relation between `U` and `clazz`, they just both need to be subclasses of `Controller`.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for the confusion. `when at all times they are the same` means all the time whenever I instantiate `ViewHelper`, I would always pass in the same type. In a way, by not passing the type twice, it would also be able to avoid the possibility for me to pass in two different types like your example. So, that is now my problem. How do I achieve it?

Comment: You don't, because the `ViewHelper` class is *explicitly* declared to support them being different, so it requires that both are specified.

Comment: @Andreas I was the one who coded ViewHelper. How is it possible to modify `ViewHelper` so that I would only pass in `MainController` either via diamond operator (`<>`) or constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a static method to be called instead of the constructor.

```java
public static <T extends Parent, U extends Controller> ViewHelper<T, U> of(Class<T> componentType, Class<U> controllerType) throws IOException {
    return new ViewHelper<T, U>(controllerType);
}
```

You then call it like this:

```java
var viewHelper = ViewHelper.of(BorderPane.class, MainController.class);
```

Comment: This works like a charm.  To force creating instance of `ViewHelper` with only `of()` method, I make the constructor `private`. Thank you much.